# SSIS Unable to Move File on OnTaskFailed Event Handler

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, ssis

I have a package the loops through multiple Flat Files, parses them with a script component and gets them into my Database. The idea is that the package points to a shared folder and loops through all the files. If the data is successfully imported, the package deletes the file afterwards. Once the foreach loop is empty (all the files are successfully imported), the package deletes all the contents of the directory, in case there any unwanted files/directories the package didn't loop through. 
Currently my control flow looks like this:

[image: Control Flow]

My Data Flow looks like this (Please ignore the warning, it is just an error for possible truncation):

[image: Data Flow]

Now if any of my tasks were to fail, I want my file to be moved to another directory, so the rest of the files can be imported and the trouble file can be dealt with at a later time. 
My event handler is a File System task set to move the file OnTaskFailed. This is set for the entire scope of my package. When executing the package with a file I know will cause it to fail, I get this error message:

> [File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "The process cannot access the file ' \UNCpath\filepath\file.txt' because it is being used by another process.".

How can I unlock this file so it can be moved to another folder on error? I have delay validation set to true on the file system task. I have also tried including a script component that makes the package wait ten second before trying to move it. I have no idea what other processes are using the file.

If there any other better ways to handle what I am trying to accomplish, I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Could you try, instead, using a On failure task flow, rather than an event handler. it might that the task is still "in progress" while the event handler is running; thus if you use a new node the file might be released. This is the way I tend to do things for tasks like this, and I don't run into the error you have.

Comment: If '\UNCpath\filepath\file.txt' is supposed to be a UNC path, it is incorrect, since it should start with a double-backslash

Comment: Also can you confirm that the id the package runs under actually has the  required access to the file?

Comment: its not UNC path. thats an error in my example.its also not a permission issue.

Comment: @Larnu I tried using a failure task flow instead, but i get the same error as the Eventhandler OnTaskFailed

Comment: I actually think I figured out whats locking the file. In my code I am using: var lines = File.ReadLines(filepath); If the code breaks I believe this is what is still holding the file and preventing it to move. I am not sure how to close this process on error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out why the file was locking. In my code I was using the following:

```
 var lines = File.ReadLines(filepath);
```

A foreach loop that would go through each line of the document. The thing is, File.ReadLines locks the file in place and reads through line by line. So when my code threw an error, File.ReadLines was preventing it from being moved.

To fix the issue, I changed the code to:

```
 var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
```

This stores all the text into memory, so it no longer needs to lock the file in place. It may not perform as well, but I would much rather have safer error handling.

Comment: This is even easier that you are doing it in C#. Never leave the C#. Use a try catch and move the file in the catch. However, I probably would just write out the bad line to a different path and cite the filename, linenumber to look at later.

Comment: Good advice, and something I would definitely consider. However, there's other people who need to review and maintain these packages who are not as familiar with programming. For that reason I only do what I need to in C#. However I agree that it is always the better choice. There's too many gotchyas in SSIS

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the looping file system task holds the OS file handles while the loop is active, so you can't delete or move them. You will have to convert your file moving logic from "move" to "copy" (inside loop) and "delete" (outside loop).

Create an flow that follows the error result of your Data Flow Task and copies the failed file to your failed files destination. Then your Empty Directory task will handle the deletes.

Comment: But won't the package keep failing if the file isn't deleted from the directory its pointing to?

Comment: Yes, but your "Empty Directory" task deletes them all at the end, right?. Or do you mean inside the failed files directory? If so, it would fail if you try to copy a file with the exact same name with the no-overwrite option.

Comment: It successfully copies the file into the failed directory, but foreach loop fails and does not execute the Empty Directory task. My need to delete the file afterwards was so that the package could re-execute and not try and parse the same flat file that threw an error.

Comment: You can modify the DTS so it doesn't stop if it fails. Either increment the maximum error count at a package level or create an empty OnError handler with a disabled Propagate system variable on your DataFlow task (so the error never bubbles up and breaks your flow).

Comment: There's no way to get the move task to work? The way I posted in the OP originally did work until out of nowhere it started throwing the process is being used by something else.

Comment: If there is another process holding the file, then there's nothing you can do, maybe wait and try again after some time. You can check which process is holding the file with the Process Explorer or Filemon (if Windows, on the remote server). However, if it's the same package you are running, then you are out of options. Maybe a version upgrade made a change so that it started bugging out now. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c43d6210-8a95-4170-b982-527ef800c878/moving-files-in-ssis-in-a-foreach-loop?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Increased the maximum error count to 100 using the method you previously suggested, but it still failed.